# CloudKit subscriptions and UNNotificationServiceExtension

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, cloudkit, ios10

So in iOS 10 you can now write notification service extensions that "intercept" push notifications so that you can download stuff and handle them before displaying them to the user.

However they require that the push payload has the `'mutable-content'` key in `aps` set to 1. CloudKit subscriptions do not seem to return this key in the `userInfo` dictionary (At least `CKDatabaseSubscription` doesn't), and so the service extension doesn't get called.

Is there a way to get CloudKit subscription notifications to work with `UNNotificationServiceExtensions`?

Comment: I assume you only can intercept if the app is from the same developer account? If that is so, then you can easilly create an extension or app that creates a subscription to the same CloudKit container where you want the notifications from. There is no need to intercept push notifications.

Comment: @Edwin Vermeer I guess intercept is the wrong word, the main purpose of these service extensions is that it allows you to download images etc. that aren't included in the push payload so that you can display them inline with the notification. You can't set media attachments alone on `CKNotificationInfo`. These notifications are coming from the same app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible in iOS 11, look for the `shouldSendMutableContent` property in `CKNotificationInfo`

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this does not appear to be possible.

(There is [a post on Apple's forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65124) where a developer suggests that someone create this as a feature request. Someone already did, I plan on duplicating the request.)